# JWebBrowser how to navigate dynamically

Tags: java, swing

I want to navigate to a particular url in JWebBrowser. What I did:

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                
            getEngine().getWebBrowserFrame().getWebBrowserOuterPanel().getWebBrowser().navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number");                
            getEngine().getWebBrowserFrame().setVisible(true);                          
        }
    });
```

`getEngine().getWebBrowserFrame().getWebBrowserOuterPanel().getWebBrowser()` method returns the `JWebBrowser`, which resides withing `WebBrowserOuterPanel` of `WebBrowserFrame` and the `getEngine().getWebBrowserFrame()` returns `WebBrowserFrame`.

But the problem is that it does not navigate. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does `navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number")` return true? If it does then you're doing nothing wrong (according to the [documentation](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html#navigate%28java.lang.String%29)) and it might be some bug in the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the frame that contains the web browser visible? If it is not, then the web browser never gets created and the navigate call is just waiting for this to happen.

If the purpose is to not show the parent frame, then you need at least to call frame.addNotify() to activate native components creation.